# How can I create a TwitterCore TwitterSession via ParseTwitterUtils

Tags: java, android, twitter, parse-platform, twitter-fabric

I am using Parse and Twitter in one place.

I sign up and log in my user via `ParseTwitterUtils`. This only provides me with the user's `twitter handle`, `auth_token`, `auth_secret` and and `screen_name`. But I need more e.g. `full name`, `profile picture` etc.

I am trying to avoid using `twitter4j` and use TwitterCore Kit from Twitter. For that I need to create a `TwitterSession` to able to call the service methods

The constructor for `TwitterSession` is defined as such,

`public TwitterSession(TwitterAuthToken token,
                      long userId,
                      String userName)`

Now I want to create a `TwitterAuthToken` but there is no method providing me with a way to do that. `TwitterAuthToken` has no public constructors nor creators.

There are no javadocs or guides for doing this.

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a TwitterAuthToken using the public constructor
TwitterAuthToken(String token,String secret)

```
TwitterAuthToken auth = new TwitterAuthToken(auth_token,auth_secret);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check snipplets from [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-twitter-feed-reader/). There is a method the get the token:

```
   public TwitterAuthToken getTwitterAuthToken(String twitterKeyBase64) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TWITTER_TOKEN_URL);
    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + twitterKeyBase64);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
    HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
    String twitterJsonResponse = httpUtil.getHttpResponse(httpPost);
    return convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(twitterJsonResponse);
}
```